# What's the difference between Theta(n) and T(n) when considering time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, mergesort

The professor was discussing the time complexity of merge sort and he divided the whole process into three steps.

1. check whether the size of array is 1 -> time complexity: theta(1)
2. He described the sorting process -> time complexity: 2T(n/2)
3. Merge the tow sorted sequences -> time complexity: theta(n)

I don't understand step 2, why did he describe it as 2T(n/2) instead of 2Theta(n/2)? What's the difference between theta(n) and T(n)?

Here is the link from Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JPyuH4qXLZ0

And it's between 1:08:45 - 1:10:33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the professor means by `T(n)`, is the exact complexity, i.e. the number of steps the algorithm needs to complete, which actually may vary depending on the implementation. What's more interesting, is the [asymptotic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), which is here denoted as `Θ(n)`, and shows how fast `T` grows along with `n`.

The first step of the [mergesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) algorithm is to split the array into halves and sort each half with the same algorithm (which is therefore recursive). That step takes obviously `2T(n/2)`. Then you merge both halves (hence the name), that takes linear time, `Θ(n)`. From that recursive definition `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + Θ(n)` he derives that `T(n) = Θ(nlogn)` which is the complexity class of the mergesort algorithm.